Geoserver API - "the specified coverage is not available"
I am using GeoServer 2.26.0 (docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.26.0), and the only extension I have installed is NetCDF; otherwise, it is a vanilla install.
I have created a NetCDF store and successfully published a Layer using the UI. However, when I make a duplicate layer via the API (POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/uk-msl/coverages), I get the following stack trace when "previewing" said layer;
09:34:43 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the specified coverage is not available: 2024-10-27
        at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFReader.checkIsSupported(NetCDFReader.java:658)
        at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFReader.getMetadataNames(NetCDFReader.java:195)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.SingleGridCoverage2DReader.getMetadataNames(SingleGridCoverage2DReader.java:79)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.getMetadataNames(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:356)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.util.ReaderDimensionsAccessor.<init>(ReaderDimensionsAccessor.java:131)
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:492)
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:107)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.parseRequestKVP(Dispatcher.java:1547)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:720)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:259)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
        at org.geoserver.filters.HTTPMethodFilter.doFilter(HTTPMethodFilter.java:36)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
        at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:352)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:168)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:225)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:190)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:141)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
        at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
        at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:383)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:937)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

When I compare the configuration using the API between the working, manually created layer and the API layer they are basically the same (GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/uk-msl/coveragestores/2024-10-27/coverages/2024-10-27.json);
{
  "coverage": {
    "name": "2024-10-27",
    "nativeName": "2024-10-27",
    "namespace": {
      "name": "uk-msl",
      "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/rest/namespaces/uk-msl.json"
    },
    "title": "2024-10-27",
    "description": "Generated from NetCDF",
    "keywords": { "string": ["msl", "WCS", "NetCDF"] },
    "nativeCRS": "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\", \n  DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\", \n    SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]], \n    AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]], \n  PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\", 0.0, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]], \n  UNIT[\"degree\", 0.017453292519943295], \n  AXIS[\"Geodetic longitude\", EAST], \n  AXIS[\"Geodetic latitude\", NORTH], \n  AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]",
    "srs": "EPSG:4326",
    "nativeBoundingBox": {
      "minx": -30.125,
      "maxx": 20.125,
      "miny": 34.875,
      "maxy": 70.125,
      "crs": "EPSG:4326"
    },
    "latLonBoundingBox": {
      "minx": -30.125,
      "maxx": 20.125,
      "miny": 34.875,
      "maxy": 70.125,
      "crs": "EPSG:4326"
    },
    "projectionPolicy": "REPROJECT_TO_DECLARED",
    "enabled": true,
    "metadata": {
      "entry": [
        { "@key": "elevation", "dimensionInfo": { "enabled": false } },
        {
          "@key": "time",
          "dimensionInfo": {
            "enabled": true,
            "presentation": "LIST",
            "units": "ISO8601",
            "defaultValue": { "strategy": "MINIMUM" },
            "nearestMatchEnabled": false,
            "rawNearestMatchEnabled": false,
            "startValue": "",
            "endValue": ""
          }
        },
        { "@key": "cachingEnabled", "$": "false" },
        { "@key": "dirName", "$": "2024-10-27_msl" }
      ]
    },
    "store": {
      "@class": "coverageStore",
      "name": "uk-msl:2024-10-27",
      "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/uk-msl/coveragestores/2024-10-27.json"
    },
    "serviceConfiguration": false,
    "simpleConversionEnabled": false,
    "nativeFormat": "NetCDF",
    "grid": {
      "@dimension": 2,
      "range": { "low": "0 0", "high": "201 141" },
      "transform": {
        "scaleX": 0.25,
        "scaleY": -0.25,
        "shearX": 0,
        "shearY": 0,
        "translateX": -30,
        "translateY": 70
      },
      "crs": "EPSG:4326"
    },
    "supportedFormats": { "string": ["GEOTIFF", "GIF", "PNG", "JPEG", "TIFF"] },
    "interpolationMethods": {
      "string": ["nearest neighbor", "bilinear", "bicubic"]
    },
    "defaultInterpolationMethod": "nearest neighbor",
    "dimensions": {
      "coverageDimension": {
        "name": "msl",
        "description": "GridSampleDimension[-Infinity,Infinity]",
        "range": { "min": "-inf", "max": "inf" },
        "nullValues": { "double": "NaN" },
        "dimensionType": { "name": "REAL_64BITS" }
      }
    },
    "requestSRS": { "string": "EPSG:4326" },
    "responseSRS": { "string": "EPSG:4326" },
    "parameters": {
      "entry": [
        { "string": "Bands", "null": "" },
        { "string": "Filter", "null": "" }
      ]
    },
    "nativeCoverageName": "2024-10-27"
  }
}

Naturally, I tracked this down in the source code (https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/plugin/coverage-multidim/netcdf/src/main/java/org/geotools/coverage/io/netcdf/NetCDFReader.java#L658). However, it wasn't obvious what was wrong, and I'm not a Java developer, so that's as far as I could take that one.
Interestingly (used in the loosest of terms), when I go to view the layer created via the API in the UI, when I click on the "dimension" tab I am met with this stacktrace (just in case it's related, although could be a separate issue);
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.geoserver.web.publish.PublishedConfigurationPage.createTabPanel(PublishedConfigurationPage.java:242)
    at org.geoserver.web.publish.PublishedConfigurationPage$4.getPanel(PublishedConfigurationPage.java:184)
    at org.geoserver.web.publish.PublishedConfigurationPage$4.getPanel(PublishedConfigurationPage.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.web.publish.PublishedConfigurationPage$5$1.onSubmit(PublishedConfigurationPage.java:206)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1312)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:687)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor256.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:216)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doPost(WicketServlet.java:159)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.HTTPMethodFilter.doFilter(HTTPMethodFilter.java:36)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:352)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:101)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:225)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:190)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at 

Any help or advice will be well received.
----- EDIT *******
As requested ncdump -h (minorly edited as not sure of copyright issues from source)
{
dimensions:
        longitude = 201 ;
        latitude = 141 ;
        time = 9 ;
        variable = 1 ;
        string3 = 3 ;
variables:
        float longitude(longitude) ;
                longitude:_FillValue = NaNf ;
                longitude:units = "degrees_east" ;
                longitude:long_name = "longitude" ;
        float latitude(latitude) ;
                latitude:_FillValue = NaNf ;
                latitude:units = "degrees_north" ;
                latitude:long_name = "latitude" ;
        int time(time) ;
                time:long_name = "time" ;
                time:units = "days since 2024-10-27 00:00:00" ;
                time:calendar = "proleptic_gregorian" ;
        double msl(time, latitude, longitude) ;
                msl:_FillValue = NaN ;
        char variable(variable, string3) ;
                variable:_Encoding = "utf-8" ;
        double msl_scaled(variable, time, latitude, longitude) ;
                msl_scaled:_FillValue = NaN ;
        int class(time) ;
}


Please share the original and duplicate netCDF file or at the very least paste output from ncdump -h <your files>.nc. How did you create the duplicate layer? NetCDF support in geotools has some limitations, but more likely the coverage name was not properly copied to the duplicate layer from the original.

@Patrick, you were correct; "nativeCoverageName" was incorrect as it should have been "msl", the variable name in the netCDF file. The value I set, "2024-10-27", was the name I was trying to give the layer. Put this as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct; otherwise, I'll answer it myself which feels wrong but I hate loose ends :-)

The netCDF data does not have a data variable called 2024-10-27. From the header dump it becomes clear that you should use the msl data variable as that is the only netCDF variable that geoserver would support, looking at the dimensions.
As per your comment, you can give the layer the name 2024-10-27 after you create the layer from the msl data variable.
